# How do I flatten a table for an entire population?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently working to replace an update process which currently iterates over a very large table using a PL/SQL cursor, updating several columns with flattened data.

The query is structured such that the flattened results can only return a single row, by limiting to term and id.  The term_eff column indicates when an activity should start appearing in results, but there is no current limitation for an end date.  How can I return the flattened results of the test_activity table for all rows in the test_person table?

Test case tables:

```
create table test_person (id number,term varchar2(6));
create table test_activity(id number,term_eff varchar2(6),activity varchar2(10));
insert into test_person values(1,'201001');
insert into test_person values(1,'201101');
insert into test_person values(1,'201102');
insert into test_person values(2,'201001');
insert into test_person values(2,'201101');
insert into test_person values(2,'201102');
insert into test_activity values (1,'201001','Jump');
insert into test_activity values (1,'201001','Play');
insert into test_activity values (1,'201102','Run');
insert into test_activity values (2,'201001','Jump');
insert into test_activity values (2,'201101','Play');
insert into test_activity values (2,'201101','Run');
commit;
```

Here is the current query to return a single row.  Would like a version of this that can return values for all rows in the test_person table.

```
select Max(CASE WHEN A.activity_rank = 1 THEN A.activity ELSE NULL END) AS activity1,
       Max(CASE WHEN A.activity_rank = 2 THEN A.activity ELSE NULL END) AS activity2,
       Max(CASE WHEN A.activity_rank = 3 THEN A.activity ELSE NULL END) AS activity3
  from (SELECT id, 
               term_eff,
               activity,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY term_eff desc) AS activity_rank
          FROM test_activity
         WHERE id = 1
           AND term_eff <= '201001') A;
```

Edit: Expected results from the final query:

```
ID  Term    Activity1   Activity2   Activity3
1   201001  Jump        Play    
1   201101  Jump        Play
1   201102  Jump        Play        Run
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just remove the `where` condition and add a `group by`.  You've already done the hard part:

```
select id,
       Max(CASE WHEN A.activity_rank = 1 THEN A.activity ELSE NULL END) AS activity1,
       Max(CASE WHEN A.activity_rank = 2 THEN A.activity ELSE NULL END) AS activity2,
       Max(CASE WHEN A.activity_rank = 3 THEN A.activity ELSE NULL END) AS activity3
from (SELECT id, term_eff, activity,
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY term_eff desc) AS activity_rank
      FROM test_activity
      WHERE term_eff <= '201001'
     ) A
group by id;
```

Comment: While this would work if the term code was fixed, the term_eff where statement also needs to be altered to what is in the test_person table.

Comment: @JasonK.  . . . I don't even know why you have that condition in your query.  If this is supposed to be a date, then you should use a native database date type, such as the aptly named `date`.

Comment: It's an ID column for a term, which is made by year and an ID number, so it doesn't quite fit into a date field.  It just happens to look like a date in the simplified test case.  In the real app, the IDs can go up to 99.